# Code only works normally if I loop it four times

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, for-loop, optimization

So, I'm trying to make a Terraria-like game and I didn't find anywhere a normal way to make lighting with Tilemaps like in there, so I decided to make my own. I coded it and it generally works, but I have some big problems with it.

```
public class Lighting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int[,] lighting;
    [SerializeField] Tilemap tp;
    private void Start()
    {
        Lighting.lighting = new int[tp.cellBounds.max.x, tp.cellBounds.max.y];
    }
 
    public static IEnumerator UpdateLighting(Tilemap tp) //Ran at the start of the scene
    {
        for (int y = tp.cellBounds.min.y; y < tp.cellBounds.max.y; y++)
        {
            for (int x = tp.cellBounds.min.x; x < tp.cellBounds.max.x; x++)
            {
                if (tp.GetTile(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0)) == null)
                {
                    Lighting.lighting[x, y] = 15; //placing max lighting in air blocks
                }
            }
        }
        Right();
        Right();
        Right();
        Right();
        IEnumerator Right()
        {
            for (int y = tp.cellBounds.min.y; y < tp.cellBounds.max.y; y++)
            {
                for (int x = tp.cellBounds.min.x; x < tp.cellBounds.max.x; x++)
                {
                    if (tp.GetTile(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0)) != null)
                    {
                        int maxlight = 0;
                        if (((y + 1) < tp.cellBounds.max.y) && (lighting[x, y + 1] > maxlight))
                        {
                            maxlight = Lighting.lighting[x, y + 1]; //Up position from block
                        }
                        if (((x + 1) < tp.cellBounds.max.x) && (lighting[x + 1, y] > maxlight))
                        {
                            maxlight = Lighting.lighting[x + 1, y]; //Right position from block
                        }
                        if (((x - 1) > tp.cellBounds.min.x) && (Lighting.lighting[x - 1, y] > maxlight))
                        {
                            maxlight = lighting[x - 1, y]; //Left position from block
                        }
                        if (((y - 1) > tp.cellBounds.min.y) && (lighting[x, y - 1] > maxlight))
                        {
                            maxlight = lighting[x, y - 1]; //Down position from block
                        }
                        lighting[x, y] = Mathf.Clamp(maxlight - 3, 0, 15);
                        float tc = lighting[x, y] / 15f; //calculating the color of the light(because 1 is white and 0 is black)
                        tp.SetColor(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0), new Color(tc, tc, tc, 1)); //setting the color of the tile
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Basically, in the start of the scene, I use this function. It creates a two dimensional int to represent the lighting grid and then goes through every block of the air and puts the lighting at 15. Then it goes through every normal block and checks the surrounding blocks and makes the lighting the max lighting of surrounding blocks - 3, then calculates the color and sets the tile to that color.

[Normally working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K5mv.png)

If I call the function `Right();` only one time, this happens

[Game not working normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU3Xa.png)

I guessed that this happens, because it only goes from left to right, so I just tried doing it multiple times. But it doesn't make sense, why it doesn't work with just one loop. And it lags a lot if I update lighting after each block placement or breaking, so I need a way to optimize it and just find out why it doesn't work

Comment: Looks like your missing yield’s on your Right() calls. Without yielding, all four will be running in parallel instead of waiting for the previous call to finish.

Comment: @Studwell The `Right()` method isn't actually an iterator, it processes the map entirely when called. That's the thing he's calling 4 times to get anything to happen.

Answer (score 0):

> I guessed that this happens, because it only goes from left to right, so I just tried doing it multiple times. But it doesn't make sense, why it doesn't work with just one loop.

I would say the simplest way to explain why it doesn't work with just one loop is because you're only checking the adjacent tiles for illumination. The reason this doesn't work is because a light source may be two tiles to the right of the tile you're updating and the tile to the immediate right hasn't yet been updated so it reports a value of 0. You would need to search within a 5-tile radius of the tile you're attempting to update.

I'm sure there are plenty of solutions to this problem, but only two come to mind. Either you loop through all light sources and propagate the illumination from them or loop through all of the non-light source tiles looking for the closest light source. I can't provide a specific algorithm for you to accomplish this that would be efficient in any regard, but I hope this helps.

> And it lags a lot if I update lighting after each block placement or breaking, so I need a way to optimize it and just find out why it doesn't work

Typically, games don't reevaluate all tiles' lighting on every tick. The only time lighting needs to change is if a tile is modified (light source or otherwise). I would say the best way to think about this from a Terraria perspective is think about placing a torch in an unlit cave. A new light source appears in the middle of an unlit square and only those within a 5-tile radius need to be updated. Likewise, removing said torch will only affect that same 5-tile radius.

If you want to get really fancy like Terraria, placing an opaque block between a light source and a non-light source should further diminish the power of the light source. The lovely diagram below emulates the possibility of this.

```cs
T - Torch or Light Source
B - Opaque block
# - Lighting power
        |1|
      |1|2|1|
    |1|2|3|2|1|
  |1|2|3|4|3|2|1|
|1|2|3|4|T|4|B|1|
  |1|2|3|4|3|2|1|
    |1|2|3|2|1|
      |1|2|1|
        |1|
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am currently trying to make this work and so far it's going not that good. I am confused on how to make sun lighting, because some blocks of air don't need to be fully lit, but others need to.
I think I can make this work by checking up on the y axis if there is a block in that direction and if there is, then make calculations to it, like it is a normal block. I know it sounds very confusing